# WPF: How to place a Popup on a BlockUIContainer?

Tags: wpf, popup, mouse

The Popup class has a PlacementTarget which can be used to position the Popup relatively to a UIElement.

```
Popup p = new Popup();
p.PlacementTarget = someUIElement;
```

This is ok but in my case I have a BlockUIContainer (as part of a FlowDocument) and I want a Popup to be opened when the mouse cursor enters the BlockUIContainer. The problem is that the BlockUIContainer is NOT an UIElement.

Does anyone know a solution?

Or can anyone suggest how the screen position of a BlockUIContainer (or any other Block) can be determined? (Then one could use absolute positioning to place the Popup.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you just use the BlockUIContainer's `Child` as PlacementTarget? Just a guess...

Comment: @Clemens: This is exactly what I ended up doing. I had the same problem with a Table and solved it a similar way (by inserting an invisible row with a BlockUIContainer (height=0) serving as PlacementTarget).